# Не могу применить стиль к элементу панели

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-webforms

Не получается применить стиль к динамическим элементам.
.aspx файл страницы:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Index" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlProducts" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

В .aspx.cs. в Page_Load сделал следующее:

```
foreach (Product product in products) 
{ 
Panel productPanel = new Panel(); 
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(); 
imageButton.CssClass = "productImage";
productPanel.Controls.Add(imageButton);       
pnlProducts.Controls.Add(productPanel);
}
```

Ну и сам участок css-кода, привязанный из masterpage'a :

```
#ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlProducts div {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}

.productImage {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    vertical-align: central;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Стиль не применился. В чём я ошибся и что исправить?

Answer (score 0):

```
pnlProducts.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;

#pnlProducts div {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Вместо #ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlProducts div { ... }?

Comment: да *(8 символов нужно...)*